# Using a request header value in @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-expression-language

Is it possible to use a request header value in @PreAuthorize?

In my app, all requests have a custom header included which I need to use in conjunction with the user role to determine whether or not they should be allowed to access the controller.

It's ok if someone manually specifies a header as that won't be a security issue, as ultimately the role will control this. But I will need to use it to cut down on checking for that manually in each controller method.

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: `@Controller` ? `@RestController` ?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, in a @RestController class

Comment: if you want to execute such request for every call, why not to write a filter ??

Comment: A lot of controller methods need this but not all... @JuanBC.  Thank you all for your answers and responses!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 - This may be the fastest method if you will only use it in a few places.

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/private-api-method")
@PreAuthorize("#request.getHeader('header-name') == 'localhost:8080'")
public ResponseEntity<String> privateApiMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK!");
}
```

`OR`

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/private-api-method")
@PreAuthorize("#header == 'localhost:8080'")
public ResponseEntity<String> privateApiMethod(@RequestHeader("header-name") String header) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK!");
}
```

2 - This may be the best method if you will use it in many places.

*(In the `SecurityService`, you can add multiple different methods of checking.)*

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/private-api-method")
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.checkHeader(#request)")
public ResponseEntity<String> privateApiMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK!");
}
```

3 - You can choose a special method for yourself

[A Custom Security Expression with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression)

Answer (score 1):

Since you intend to check for a particular header/cookie/request-attribute for every controller methods, you should opt for a Filter as this would be a standard and you can have a guarantee for it be executed for each and every method and that too only once by extending from `OncePerRequestFilter`

Having said that, there would be 2 way you can achieve this:

1. By extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` or `OncePerRequestFilter`

   For this you may refer the spring-security jwt token validation flow which all would advocate for:

   - Add method security at your desired controller method as `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER_ROLE')")`
   - Intercept the request before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, extract the `Authentication` header or `cookies` from the request and validate the token value for claims.

```java
public class CustomHeaderAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter{

@Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

// Get all the headers from request, throw exception if your header not found    
Enumeration<String> reqHeaders =  request.getHeaderNames();

    Assert.notNull(reqHeaders, "No headers found. Abort operation!");

    Collections.list(reqHeaders)
        .stream()
        .filter(header_ -> header_.equals("TARGET_HEADER_NAME"))
.findAny().ifPresent(header_ -> {
          // header found, would go for success-andler
    });
    
    // Here it means request has no target header
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, new CustomException(""));
  }

}
```

Going by this way, you need to register your filter with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and you may also provide your `AuthenticationProvider` if you extend from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

2. By accessing `HTTP Headers` in rest controllers using `@RequestHeader` as [dm-tr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544490/5324721) has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_SOMETHING')")
@RequestMapping("PATH")
public void checkIt(@RequestHeader("header-name") String header) {
    if (null != header /* && header meets certain condition*/) {
        // stuff
    } else throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN); // PERMISSION NOT GRANTED, 403 ERROR
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Putting that approach together with doing a SEL check here, I'm curious if this may work: @PreAuthorize(@myEvaluationService.checkSecurity(#header, hasAuthority(ROLE_SOMETHING))) -- not this exactly as the syntax is definitely wrong, but looks like it may be possible to externalize to a service. I'll dig in and respond on the post with how it went. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Replace my comment `/* && header..... */` with your condition `@myEvaluationService.checkSecurity(header)`